# Meteor froala:editor-reactive save on change of data

Tags: javascript, meteor, froala, atmosphere.js

I have Meteor project which uses the froala:editor-reactive package in order to set the user's about me field.

Here is my template js code:

```
Template.profile.helpers({
  getAbout: function() {
    return Meteor.user().profile.about;
  },
  doSave: function (e, editor) {        
    // Get edited HTML from Froala-Editor
    var newHTML = editor.getHTML();
    // Do something to update the edited value provided by the Froala-Editor plugin, if it has changed:
    if (!_.isEqual(newHTML, Meteor.user().profile.about)) {
      Meteor.call("updateTestimony", Meteor.userId(), newHTML);
    }
    return false; // Stop Froala Editor from POSTing to the Save URL
  }
}
```

Here is my template html code:

```
<template name="profile">
  <div>
    {{> froalaReactive _onbeforeSave=doSave _value=getAbout}}
  </div>
</template>
```

It's supposed to save as the value changes (I hope).
But I have an error with the line `var newHTML = editor.getHTML();` and I've also tried `var newHTML = editor.html.get(true);`.  Both of these result in an error where it cannot read the property of html or getHTML.  I'm hoping this is just a syntax error and I need something else but what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Per the plugin docs](https://github.com/froala/froala-reactive), try:

```
var newHTML = editor.html.get(true /* keep_markers */);
```

If that doesn't work, you may possibly be using a different version. In which case, give the following syntaxes a shot:

```
var newHTML = $('.your_selector').editable('getHTML', true, true);

var newHTML = $('.your_selector').froalaEditor('html.get', true);
```

More from the official docs [here](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/methods#html.get) and see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33347868/froala-editor-on-meteorjs-get-editor-content).